# Redirect www.www Sub-Sub-domain link to domain name to fix 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a single link (no wild card)

http://www.www.example.com
to
https://www.example.com

This www. www sub domain link is linking to our site from an authority site and leading to a 404 page. If I can redirect it to our main site, the link juice will flow correctly.

I have tried the redirect code for sub-sub domain to the domain as advised earlier, but it does not work in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 http://www.www.example.com  https://www.example.com
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.www.example.com [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com [L, R=301]
```

All these codes do not work

Comment: The attempt with `Redirect` can not work - that expects a URL _path_ beginning with a slash as the old URL to match, not an absolute URL. As for the attempt using the rewrite engine - I am not sure environment variables are case insensitive, that should rather be `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: `@misorude` Tried that with all caps for `%{HTTP_HOST}`. The browser says www.www.example.com’s server IP address could not be found. Updated code on main question.

Comment: _“The browser says www.www.example.com’s server IP address could not be found.”_ - well if that sub-sub-domain can not be resolved by the DNS yet, you need to make that possible first of all. You can not redirect any visitor, if they don’t even reach your server in the first place.

Comment: Ok I was able to create a www.www subdomain using simple DNS manager. But adding above code does not work

Comment: Tried this from elsewhere on Stack, but does not work
    ```RewriteEngine on```
    ```RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.www\.example\.com [NC]```
    ```RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www\.example.com [L, R=301]```

Comment: The substitution part doesn’t use regex, so you should not escape characters like the dot in there.

Comment: `@misorude` have removed \ and posted code in first post. The www.www.example.com shows valid page with hosting holding ad-filled page. But the redirect does not work as above

Comment: Also what I see is www has started redirecting to www.www and the holding page.

Comment: What does the  double www subdomain point to in your hosting setup? Does it point to the same directory as the normal site, where the .htaccess is located? Or did it get set up pointing to a different directory next to the main site’s document root, or a sub folder?